# C# wpf saving "files", settings, state

Tags: c#, wpf, state

I'm trying to learn about saving state and settings in my applications.

As a simple example, say I have an application where I drag images onto a canvas from explorer. What is the best way to save this info if I want to get it back?

I would have to save -> the images path, and where it is on the Canvas.

So the very simple solution would be to create and save a text file with values for path of image, and Canvas.GetTop and Canvas.GetLeft.

```
"C:\\users\\<username\\pic1.png", 100, 150
"C:\\users\\<username\\pic2.png", 300, 400
```

then load them when I want.

What is the better solution, and how is this done in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get .Left and stuff during the OnClosing(...) event. Just save that to an XML file and in public MainWindow(), just read the XML file and load the settings